# What to do with the auto-created index when applying a foreign key constraint in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, indexing

When a foreign key constraint is placed on on a MySQL table, an index is automatically added by MySQL for better performance. I'm totally ok with this. It's all in the docs.

But, when deleting the foreign key, I noticed that the auto-created index itself is not deleted. And that's not in de docs. I'm wondering:

1. Will it get ever deleted automatically, since MySQL did create it for me too?
2. How large can a foreign key index get? If it's only a few kilobytes, I'm not bothered, but what if it gets large...?

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html only says this:
>
> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
> foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
> referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
> columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an
> index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
> exist. This index might be silently dropped later if you create
> another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint.
> index_name, if given, is used as described previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A foreign key index is just like a regular secondary index. It will grow proportionally to the number of rows in the table, and the data type in the indexed column(s).

It might still be useful to have this index if you run queries that need it. It's common in MySQL deployments to avoid foreign key constraints, but keep the indexes to support optimizing joins or searches.

If you don't need that index, i.e. if you have no queries that use the index, then you can drop it.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me why you call it common to avoid foreign keys? Why should you not use this since this is forcing integrety? And second, I'm using a framework that uses migrations that applies the foreign keys. When dropping the foreign key, shouldn't the framwork also clean up the index MySQL created?

Comment: Like I said above, the index may still be useful to help optimize some queries. You must decide if you want to drop the index.

Comment: Foreign keys are good for enforcing referential integrity, but they can hinder other operations. For example, if you are doing data cleanup work, you might need temporarily to have orphaned records. Or if you use partitioned tables. Or you use table-rename as a method of archiving tables.

Comment: Another reason is the locking. If you update a child row, you know it locks that row. But it also locks the parent row referenced by a foreign key in the child row. This can cause lock contention in some applications, which the developer did not expect.